# rootfs building using buildroot is failing

Tags: linux-kernel, boot, root-filesystem, buildroot, beagleboneblack

I want to boot beaglebone black board with `kernel 6.5.4` image.
So I took a SDCard(8GB), formatted and make it 2 paritions using *gparted* application in ubuntu.
I have copied below boot files into BOOT partition of SDCard.

- am335x-boneblack.dtb
- MLO
- u-boot.img
- uEnv.txt
- uImage

I was able to build `kernel 6.5.4` with no errors and I got uImage & zImage kernel images.
But unable to generate rootfs that is booting my board from SDCard.
I have used Dowloaded **bone-debian-9.9-lxqt-armhf-2019-08-03-4gb.img.xz** from
[Debian 9.9 2019-08-03 4GB SD LXQT - BeagleBoard](https://www.beagleboard.org/distros/debian-9-9-2019-08-03-4gb-sd-lxqt)
first decompressed it as
`unxz bone-debian-9.9-lxqt-armhf-2019-08-03-4gb.img`

which gives us **bone-debian-9.9-lxqt-armhf-2019-08-03-4gb.img** file

Right click and opening with “Disk Image Mounter” mounted it into

> **home/waageesh/rootfs**

Post that, I copied all contents from
/home/waageesh/rootfs(rootfs decompressed from beaglebone black image file)
to
/home/waageesh/ROOTFS(parition created in SDCard, which servers as rootfs for kernel while booting on BBB)

Now tried booting BBB board from SDCard

kernel panic is coming and hanging while loading from SDCard.
Now I am building kernel modules for same kernel version and want to cross-check for ARM architecture by installing those .ko modules in /lib/modules/6.5.4 of rootfs partition in SDCard.

```
Debian GNU/Linux 9 beaglebone ttyS0

BeagleBoard.org Debian Image 2019-08-03

Support/FAQ: http://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian

default username:password is [debian:temppwd]

beaglebone login: debian
[  403.045819] 8<--- cut here ---
[  403.048935] Unable to handle kernel paging request at virtual address 2d333150 when read
[  403.057130] [2d333150] *pgd=00000000
[  403.060746] Internal error: Oops: 5 [#2] SMP ARM
[  403.065390] Modules linked in: snd_soc_hdmi_codec evdev iptable_nat nf_nat nf_conntrack nf_defrag_ipv6 nf_defrag_ipv4 snd_soc_simple_card iptable_man4
[  403.132385] CPU: 0 PID: 50 Comm: kworker/0:17 Tainted: G      D            6.5.4 #1
[  403.140082] Hardware name: Generic AM33XX (Flattened Device Tree)
[  403.146210] Workqueue:  0x0 (events)
[  403.149823] PC is at __kmem_cache_alloc_node+0xbc/0x4dc
[  403.155093] LR is at 0xe03e9e58
[  403.158249] pc : [<c02f08d8>]    lr : [<e03e9e58>]    psr: a0010013
[  403.164543] sp : e03e9e58  ip : e03e9f28  fp : 0000cc52
[  403.169791] r10: 00000000  r9 : c1005694  r8 : 00000cc0
[  403.175038] r7 : c1134598  r6 : 2d333130  r5 : 00000000  r4 : c1801100
[  403.181595] r3 : 00000020  r2 : df93bb38  r1 : 0000cc51  r0 : 1e9b4000
[  403.188153] Flags: NzCv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode SVC_32  ISA ARM  Segment none
[  403.195324] Control: 10c5387d  Table: 82ebc019  DAC: 00000051
[  403.201093] Register r0 information: non-paged memory
[  403.206175] Register r1 information: non-paged memory
[  403.211252] Register r2 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[  403.216944] Register r3 information: non-paged memory
[  403.222021] Register r4 information: slab kmem_cache start c1801100 pointer offset 0 size 124
[  403.230614] Register r5 information: NULL pointer
[  403.235343] Register r6 information: non-paged memory
[  403.240420] Register r7 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[  403.246109] Register r8 information: non-paged memory
[  403.251185] Register r9 information: non-slab/vmalloc memory
[  403.256872] Register r10 information: NULL pointer
[  403.261687] Register r11 information: non-paged memory
[  403.266851] Register r12 information: 2-page vmalloc region starting at 0xe03e8000 allocated at kernel_clone+0xa4/0x3ac
[  403.277713] Process kworker/0:17 (pid: 50, stack limit = 0x2dc970a1)
[  403.284101] Stack: (0xe03e9e58 to 0xe03ea000)
[  403.288480] 9e40:                                                       ffffffff 00000000
[  403.296697] 9e60: 00000000 00000cc0 00000020 ffffffff 00000000 df938800 00000000 00000020
[  403.304914] 9e80: c015b888 c1801100 00000cc0 00000000 00000000 c02a7e88 c015b888 ffff0a00
[  403.313131] 9ea0: 00000dc0 c0d73fdb ffffff04 df938800 00000000 c2f1c780 c0d73fe8 c0156bd0
[  403.321348] 9ec0: c1003d40 00000000 00000000 c015b888 00000000 00000000 e03e9ed8 e03e9ed8
[  403.329565] 9ee0: ffff0a00 6c427dcb df938800 c2f1c780 00000000 df938988 c1fd0000 df938820
[  403.337781] 9f00: df93885c c015b9d4 e03e9f28 c0aee730 e03e9f28 6c427dcb df93885c df938800
[  403.345998] 9f20: c01539f8 c0d73fe8 e03e9f34 c0d7f5c8 00002843 00303a30 00000000 00000000
[  403.354214] 9f40: 00000000 6c427dcb df938800 c1ff4b80 df938800 df938820 df938800 c0156ee4
[  403.362432] 9f60: c1ff4b80 00000000 e03e5ed0 c1ff5a40 c1ff5dc0 c0156bd0 c1ff4b80 c1fd0000
[  403.370649] 9f80: e03e5ed0 00000000 00000000 c015d3e8 c1ff5a40 c015d310 00000000 00000000
[  403.378865] 9fa0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 c0100174 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  403.387082] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  403.395298] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  403.403520]  __kmem_cache_alloc_node from kmalloc_trace+0x28/0xb4
[  403.409668]  kmalloc_trace from __kthread_create_on_node+0x54/0x170
[  403.415995]  __kthread_create_on_node from kthread_create_on_node+0x30/0x60
[  403.423008]  kthread_create_on_node from create_worker+0xb8/0x254
[  403.429144]  create_worker from worker_thread+0x314/0x504
[  403.434578]  worker_thread from kthread+0xd8/0xf8
[  403.439315]  kthread from ret_from_fork+0x14/0x20
[  403.444048] Exception stack(0xe03e9fb0 to 0xe03e9ff8)
[  403.449125] 9fa0:                                     00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  403.457341] 9fc0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
[  403.465556] 9fe0: 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 00000013 00000000
[  403.472207] Code: e3560000 13530000 0a0000b2 e594301c (e796c003) 
[  403.478435] ---[ end trace 0000000000000000 ]---
```

> uImage(kernel 6.5.4) + rootfs(**4.14.108-ti-r113**) -> Kernel not loading

> uImage(kernel 6.5.4) + rootfs(**4.19.94-ti-r42**) -> Kernel loading, but crashing with error **Unable to change SDCard to high speed mode** & hanging with kernel panic error

My doubt is...
Do we have  to build rootfs according to kernel version
OR
we can use any rootfs for kernel booting ? (which is not working for me as said above)

Again tried with **buildroot-2021.02.1** to generate rootfs that is compatible for linux `kernel 6.5.4`.

I tried building rootfs + kernel with same version using buildroot,
but ends up again with below error

```
>>>   Executing post-image script support/scripts/genimage.sh
board/beaglebone/genimage.cfg:30: no sub-section title/index for 'config'
INFO: cmd: "mkdir -p "/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/build/genimage.tmp"" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "rm -rf "/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/build/genimage.tmp"/*" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "mkdir -p "/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/build/genimage.tmp"" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "cp -a "/tmp/tmp.BK4lPFymRs" "/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/build/genimage.tmp/root"" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "find '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/build/genimage.tmp/root' -depth -type d -printf '%P\0' | xargs -0 -I {} touch -r '/tmp/tmp.BK4lPFymRs/{}' '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/build/genimage.tmp/root/{}'" (stderr):
INFO: cmd: "mkdir -p "/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images"" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "dd if=/dev/zero of="/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/boot.vfat" seek=16777216 count=0 bs=1 2>/dev/null" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "mkdosfs   '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/boot.vfat'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'MLO' as 'MLO' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/MLO' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'u-boot.img' as 'u-boot.img' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/u-boot.img' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'zImage' as 'zImage' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/zImage' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'uEnv.txt' as 'uEnv.txt' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/uEnv.txt' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): adding file 'am335x-boneblack.dtb' as 'am335x-boneblack.dtb' ...
INFO: vfat(boot.vfat): cmd: "MTOOLS_SKIP_CHECK=1 mcopy -bsp -i '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/boot.vfat' '/home/waageesh/embedded/ELARM/EOS/buildroot-2021.02.1/output/images/am335x-boneblack.dtb' '::'" (stderr):
INFO: hdimage(sdcard.img): adding partition 'u-boot' (in MBR) from 'boot.vfat' ...
INFO: hdimage(sdcard.img): adding partition 'rootfs' (in MBR) from 'rootfs.ext4' ...
INFO: hdimage(sdcard.img): writing MBR
```

So, I am stuck & confused.

I just want to build any kernel of required specific version & should be able to generate rootfs from that custom kernel.

What exactly am I missing here and what's the right approach to build rootfs for whatever kernel version we want ??